# Laravel not returning correct foreign key after updating the object

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys

[image]

The above code is generated like this:

```
$post = Post::findOrFail($postId);

echo "category id: " . $post->category->id."<br />";
echo "category name: ". $post->category->name;
dd($post);
exit;
```

**Post model**:

```
class Post extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'posts';

   public function category() {
      return $this->hasOne(Category::class, 'id');
   }
}
```

**Category model**:

```
class Category extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'categories';
}
```

The migration and the database seeding went well, however after updating the `Post` entry the foreign key value isn't changed.

**Migration**:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $t) {
        $t->bigIncrements('id');
        $t->timestamps();
        $t->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
        $t->foreign('category_id')
                ->references('id')->on('categories')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        $t->string('title', 255);
        $t->string('description', 255);
    });
}
```

**Updating the entry**:

```
$post_id = $data->post_id;
$category_id = $data->category_id;
$title = $data->title;
$description = $data->description;

$post = Post::where('id', $post_id)->first();

$post->category_id = $category_id;
$post->title = $title;
$post->description = $description;

$post->save();
```

I've checked the database, the entry is updated (even the foreign key), however after getting the `$post->category->id` is giving me the old value.

Here is a screenshot from the database:

[image]

**Update**
It looks like when printing out the `$post->category->id` it's showing me the post's id instead of the category id.

Comment: Are you sure you are actually updating the post?, show the code where you call update post?

Comment: @mrhn you can see the save function in my post. I've checked the database, it's updated with the new values (even the foreign key) but when I query the model to retrieve from the database it's returning me the old foreign key value. I've updated the post's category foreign key value to 4 but when accessing the `$post->category->id` is giving me 1.

Comment: I asked about how you call the update post? and do you call this line echo "category id: " . $post->category->id."<br />"; after the update?

Comment: @mrhn - you can see in my post how I save the post. It's at the end of the thread, just search for: `$post->save();`. And yes. After updating the entry I'm not getting the correct value. Actually it looks like the `$post->category->id` is returning me the post's id instead of the category's id.

Comment: @mrhn - I've checked to code, not the update function is wrong, actually the foreign key relation is not working. Echoing `$post->category_id` is showing me the correct value, however the `$post->category->id` is giving me the post's id.

Comment: You are still not answering my questions, but i think i have an idea of what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are just overwriting attributes you can't always guarantee that the category will be correct. If you utilize in built functions in `Laravel` it will reload the category.

Try with this approach and see if it works.

```
$post->category()->associate(Category::find($category_id));
```

Comment: Calling `$post->category()->associate(Category::find($post->category_id));` will throw an error: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne::associate()`. However I've managed to fix with `$category = Category::find($post->category_id);` but again, what's the point of relations if I can't use them directly, like calling from the `$post->category->name` if I need to query the `Category` model in order to get it. I think I missed something, but I don't know what.

Comment: your relationship should be belongsTo();

Comment: it's working now, thank you! `$post->category()->associate(Category::find($post->category_id));`. Do I need to call this whenever I need the foreign key object? I thought `Laravel` is making the eager loading automatically.

Comment: It is better, as Laravel does not know  when the attributes changes (or it would probably be to costly). So when you use relationship methods as save, associate or sync it will reload the relationships. The other reason is you already have loaded the post, if you fetched a new post it would be correct. Just use built in functions it is better :) if it helped remember to accept it